# Will homestead increase Ether's issuance rate?

Tags: mining, ether

This question is really simple, I was wondering if when homestead arrives Ether's issuance rate will increase as it was originally planed, because quoting [Ethereum's blog post "Ethereum Launch Process"](https://blog.ethereum.org/2015/03/03/ethereum-launch-process/)

> Homestead is where we move after Frontier. We expect the following three major changes. Ether mining will be at 100% rather than 10% of the usual reward rate

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, they ditched the 10% idea. The issuance model will not change. The rate might increase slightly, because the  block time will go to around 15 seconds instead of 17.

[Frontier Blog Post](https://blog.ethereum.org/2015/07/22/frontier-is-coming-what-to-expect-and-how-to-prepare/):

> Many of the planned Frontier gotchas (which included a chain reset at Homestead, limiting mining rewards to 10%, and centralized checkpointing) were deemed unnecessary.

[Vitalik on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/3tbwbo/planned_homestead_hard_fork_changes/cx5j4z7):

> I ran simulations on my new block time algorithm, and it actually does reduce expected block time from 17 seconds to 15 seconds as a side effect.

Comment: I accepted your answer but a link to where Ethereum makes official they no longer support the 10% idea would be really appreciated.

Comment: Good point, added links

Answer (score 3):

Elaborating on Tjaden's answer: **Issuance will increase by ~10%**.

[Vitalik - February 2016:](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/45ried/if_homestead_releases_what_will_happen_to_the/d000zgp)

> **The block time will likely decrease from ~17s to ~15s, and this will
>   increase issuance by ~10%** (this isn't an unexpected change so much as
>   a correction; the initial intent had been for a block to come every
>   ~15s but we overestimated block propagation times and so it ended up
>   coming every ~17s in Frontier)

Answer (score 0):

(I couldn't find an up-to-date, canonical answer for this. A better question for this answer would be [What is the full block reward?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/939/what-is-the-full-block-reward?noredirect=1&lq=1), but that has been duplicated to this one... )

The current issuance rate - as of the Byzantium hard-fork and [EIP-649](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/pull/669) - is set at **3 ether**, reduced from the previous 5.

As per `ByzantiumBlockReward` in [`consensus.go`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/d429a92f09e476c431830cef48690dc3784153c7/consensus/ethash/consensus.go#L37):

```
// Ethash proof-of-work protocol constants.
var (
    FrontierBlockReward    *big.Int = big.NewInt(5e+18) // Block reward in wei for successfully mining a block
    ByzantiumBlockReward   *big.Int = big.NewInt(3e+18) // Block reward in wei for successfully mining a block upward from Byzantium
    maxUncles                       = 2                 // Maximum number of uncles allowed in a single block
    allowedFutureBlockTime          = 15 * time.Second  // Max time from current time allowed for blocks, before they're considered future blocks
)
```

Comment: Hey Richard, thanks for the reply. This is an old question regarding the transition between frontier and homestead and an original proposal of increasing Ether's issuance ten-fold something that didn't happen.

Comment: Yeah - agreed, a bit out of place. I was looking for an answer to reference when answering a different question, and could only find the "What is the full block reward?" question, which is the headline I wanted, but the wrong idea. I followed the dupe to your question, but I agree, it's not the right place. I'll make a new question and add my answer, and delete this one. Thanks for following up :-)