# What is the full block reward?

Tags: ether, mining, homestead, blocks, reward

The Ethereum launch process states that with the release of *Homestead*, the Ether mining will be at [100% rather than 10%](https://blog.ethereum.org/2015/03/03/ethereum-launch-process/) of the usual reward rate.

Does that mean the full block reward would be 50 Ether? Or what is the full block reward?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an old proposal. The idea of having 10% reward in the Froniter launch was abandoned.

The Frontier network was released with 100% reward. The full block reward is and will be 5 eth (at least for PoW) even in Homestead.

You can also check the [frontier-guide](https://ethereum.gitbooks.io/frontier-guide/content/frontier.html).

Answer (score 2):

You're reading an article with old information that is no longer correct.

Homestead will be 5 ether per block just as Frontier is.

Also, this is a duplicate of: [Will homestead increase Ether's issuance rate?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/322/will-homestead-increase-ethers-issuance-rate)